# Is OnRenderSizeChanged not called properly?

Tags: wpf

I have a custom canvas that's supposed to fill itself with the maximum amount of Tile objects.

If it's resized to be bigger, it fills the empty space with additional Tiles.
If It's resized to be smaller, it removed the Tiles that are no longer visible.

This only works if I resize very slowly, otherwise it all starts to mess up.

[Correct Image http://imageshack.us/a/img585/105/50186779.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img585/105/50186779.png) 
[Correct Image http://imageshack.us/a/img267/3179/76648216.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img267/3179/76648216.png)

I must be obviously doing something wrong, the code below is the canvas:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1.View
{
    public class TileCanvas : Canvas
    {
        #region Fields

        private Boolean _firstCreation;
        private Double _heightDifference;
        private Double _widthDifference;

        #endregion // Fields

        #region Properties

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TileSizeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TileSize", typeof (Int32), typeof (TileCanvas),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(30));

        public Int32 TileSize
        {
            get { return (Int32) GetValue(TileSizeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TileSizeProperty, value); }
        }

        public Int32 Columns { get; private set; }
        public Int32 Rows { get; private set; }

        #endregion // Properties

        #region Constructors

        public TileCanvas()
        {
            _firstCreation = true;
        }

        #endregion // Constructors

        #region Methods

        #region Public

        #endregion // Methods - Public

        #region Protected

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets called when the rendering size of this control changes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sizeInfo">Information on the size change.</param>
        protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}x{1}", sizeInfo.NewSize.Width, sizeInfo.NewSize.Height);

            _widthDifference += sizeInfo.NewSize.Width - sizeInfo.PreviousSize.Width;
            _heightDifference += sizeInfo.NewSize.Height - sizeInfo.PreviousSize.Height;

            int columnDifference = 0;
            int rowDifference = 0;

            if (_widthDifference > TileSize || _widthDifference < TileSize*-1)
            {
                columnDifference = ((Int32) _widthDifference)/TileSize;
                Columns += columnDifference;
                _widthDifference = 0;
            }

            if (_heightDifference > TileSize || _heightDifference < TileSize*-1)
            {
                rowDifference = ((Int32) _heightDifference)/TileSize;
                Rows += rowDifference;
                _heightDifference = 0;
            }

            UpdateTileSet(columnDifference, rowDifference);
        }

        #endregion // Methods - Protected

        #region Private

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the number of tiles if the control changed in size.
        /// </summary>
        private void UpdateTileSet(Int32 columnChange, Int32 rowChange)
        {
            // Exit if there's no practical change
            if (columnChange == 0 && rowChange == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Delete all tiles that fall out on vertical resize
            if (rowChange < 0)
            {
                for (var row = Rows; row > Rows + rowChange; row--)
                {
                    for (var column = 0; column < Columns; column++)
                    {
                        Children.RemoveRange(GetListIndex(0, Rows), Columns);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Delete all tiles that fall out on horizontal resize
            if (columnChange < 0)
            {
                for (var column = Columns; column > Columns + columnChange; column--)
                {
                    for (var row = 0; row < Rows; row++)
                    {
                        Children.RemoveAt(GetListIndex(column, row));
                    }
                }
            }

            // Fill new rows with tiles on vertical resize
            if (rowChange > 0)
            {
                for (var row = Rows - rowChange; row < Rows; row++)
                {
                    for (var column = 0; column < Columns; column++)
                    {
                        var tile = new Tile(column, row);

                        Point position = GetCanvasPosition(column, row);
                        var index = GetListIndex(column, row);

                        SetLeft(tile, position.X);
                        SetTop(tile, position.Y);

                        Children.Insert(index, tile);
                    }
                }
            }

            // The first population is a special case that can be handled
            // by filling rows only.
            if (_firstCreation)
            {
                _firstCreation = false;
                return;
            }

            // Fill new columns with tiles on horizontal resize
            if (columnChange > 0)
            {
                for (var column = Columns - columnChange; column < Columns; column++)
                {
                    for (var row = 0; row < Rows; row++)
                    {
                        var tile = new Tile(column, row);

                        Point position = GetCanvasPosition(column, row);
                        var index = GetListIndex(column, row);

                        SetLeft(tile, position.X);
                        SetTop(tile, position.Y);

                        Children.Insert(index, tile);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the index a tile should occupy based on its column and row.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="column">The column in which this tile resides.</param>
        /// <param name="row">The row in which this tile resides.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Int32 GetListIndex(Int32 column, Int32 row)
        {
            return row*Columns + column;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the coordinates of a specific position.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="column">The column the position is in.</param>
        /// <param name="row">The row the position is in.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Point GetCanvasPosition(Int32 column, Int32 row)
        {
            var positionX = column*TileSize;
            var positionY = row*TileSize;

            return new Point(positionX, positionY);
        }

        #endregion // Methods - Private

        #endregion // Methods
    }
}
```

This is Tile.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Tile.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Tile : Border
    {
        public Tile(Int32 column, Int32 row)
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            Textfield.Text = String.Format("{0}x{1}", column, row);
        }
    }
}
```

and Tile.xaml

```
<Border x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.Tile"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Width="40" Height="40">
    <TextBlock x:Name="Textfield" FontSize="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Border>
```

Where's the issue?

Comment: Can you post your `Tile` class as well, so we can more easily test out your code?

Comment: Sure, although it's just a TextBlock in a Border.

Comment: I'm not sure about the intent of your control, but maybe this can be useful: http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/03/20/wpf-auto-arrange-animated-panel/ - It's not only about animation, it also talks about calculating item placement when resizing the control. Good luck!

Comment: The intent - well, I need a grid of Tile objects that is always full no matter the container size. Thanks for the link, I'll go read it.

Comment: Actually Joe, it seems like that's an excellent source of information that I can use. Could you add this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good source of information about how to place elements at custom positions in a WPF control: http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/03/20/wpf-auto-arrange-animated-panel/

I don't know if it applies to canvas, but placing your code inside the Measure/Arrange Override methods might yield better results.